# Товары и список категорий, к которым относится товар

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день.
Есть задача реализовать базу товаров в MySQL (более 1 000 000 записей), каждый товар относится сразу к нескольким категориям. Все это дело выводится с помощью PHP, на сайте по 10-20 товаров на странице, где в информации о товаре указывается, к каким категориям этот товар относится.
Подумываю реализовать примерно такую структуру базы:

```
categories structure
id         |name
1           First category
2           Second category
3           Third category
........

items structure
id         |name
1           First item
2           Second item
3           Third item
4           Fourth item
........

items_categories structure
item_id         |cat_id
1                1
1                3
2                2
2                3
3                1
3                2
3                3
........
```

При этом способе все прекрасно выводится с помощью всего одного запроса с `JOIN`. Но вот побаиваюсь за скорость выполнения запросов при таком большом количестве записей в таблице `items_categories`.
Посоветуйте, подойдет ли указанная выше структура ну или подскажите другой вариант реализации задачи. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это классическая структура для вашего случая, так что подойдет.